# Is this passive voice and if so, how do I change to active?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Women no longer were restricted under the control of their husbands and were able to go in pursuit for their own happiness.

Answer (score 2):

The “were restricted” is passive, but  “were able” is not. To change the passive verb to active you will need to decide or guess who is or was doing the restricting, and make that party the grammatical subject. You might just stop separating the restricting from the control and write “Husbands no longer controlled their wives.” Since the wives, however, need to be the grammatical subject of “were able” in the second part of the sentence, you will need to turn that into a relative clause. That way “wives” can be both the *object* of the first (main) clause and the *subject* of the second clause.

> Husbands no longer controlled their wives, *who* were able to go in pursuit **of** [or just *able to pursue*]  their own happiness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence is passive. To change the sentence to the active voice, the subject needs to be whoever was doing the restricting:

> _____ no longer restricted women under the control of their husbands, and women pursued their own happiness.